# Display configurable options block on customized page

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, php

I am trying to display configurable options in a custom product view page. I have added following code to page but I am getting an error:

Code:

```
 <?php $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product));?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
<div class="input-box">
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
<option><?php echo $this->__('Select...') ?></option>
</select>
 </div>
</dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

> Error:  TypeError:
>   this.config is undefined
>
> this.taxConfig  = this.config.taxConfig;

I need help in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing Javascript. Compare the scripts loaded in the `<head>` on your custom page and on the default product page.

Comment: What is actually outputted by `<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>`, If you block is not of type or does not extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable then you may find this information is missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you block is not of type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` then you could find that the function `getJsonConfig` is not being set-up correctly.

You should check your block type and also the return value of the function call.